# UIBindingObserver for UINavigationBar does not work as expected

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uinavigationbar, rx-swift

I bind to `UIBindingObserver` for `barTintColor` new `UIColor` and `title`, but it does not showing. Wired thing is that when I drag UIViewController back and release everything appear

[image]

---

### Code

```
extension Reactive where Base: UINavigationBar {
  var barTintColor: UIBindingObserver<Base, UIColor> {
    return UIBindingObserver(UIElement: self.base) { navigationBar, barTintColor in
      navigationBar.barTintColor = barTintColor
    }
  }
}

class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
   private(set) var tintColor: Variable<UIColor> = Variable(ColorConstants.tintColor)

   override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     if let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
       self.tintColor.asObservable()
         .bind(to: navigationBar.rx.barTintColor)
         .addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
      }
   }
}

 class TasksListViewController: BaseViewController {
   var viewModel: TasksListViewModel!
   ...
   override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
     self.viewModel.colorObsrvable
       .unwrap()
       .bind(to: self.tintColor)
       .addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)

    self.viewModel.titleObsrvable
     .unwrap()
     .bind(to: self.rx.title)
     .addDisposableTo(self.disposeBag)
   }
 }

 class TasksListViewModel {
   private(set) var titleObsrvable: Observable<String?>!
   private(set) var colorObsrvable: Observable<UIColor?>!

   init(from goal: Goal) {
     let goalPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "(SELF = %@)", self.goal.objectID)
     self.goalObservable = CoreDataModel.shared.rx.fetchObject(predicate: goalPredicate)
     self.titleObsrvable = goalObservable.map { $0?.name }
     self.colorObsrvable = goalObservable.map { $0?.color }
   }
 }

extension Reactive where Base: CoreDataModel {
  func fetchObjects<T: NSManagedObject>(predicate: NSPredicate? = nil) -> Observable<[T]> {
    let entityName = String(describing: T.self)
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<T>(entityName: entityName)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
    fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
    return base.managedObjectContext.rx.entities(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
 }
}
```

class `Goal` is just class Entitiy

---

### What I have tried

- Yes it's MainThread, I tested. And also run this task on GCD MainThread ❌
- added `observeOn(MainScheduler.sharedInstance)` does not help ❌
- put breakpoints inside the UIBindingObserver when drag and release it does not call ❌
- added title in storyboard to NavBar and it works, but with wired delay. First it shows "Ti..." and then "Title" ✅

Replaced(And its works✅ idk why):

```
self.titleObsrvable = goalObservable.map { $0?.name }
self.colorObsrvable = goalObservable.map { $0?.color }
```

with:

```
self.titleObsrvable = Observable.of("1234")
self.colorObsrvable = Observable.of(UIColor.red)
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

---

If you want to check whole project you can see it here:
https://github.com/Yerkenabildin/my-everest

---

Comment: If still writing, delete until finished. You can undelete at that point.

Comment: @matt imposible to edit deleted questions

Comment: Really? Sorry, I'm able to edit _my_ deleted questions, so I thought you could too. Maybe this ability is not universal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be some sort of race condition. You are setting the `barTintColor` at the same moment that the navigation controller is starting its animation. If you make sure you don't change the tin color until *after* the animation is complete, it will work the way you want.

Also, you have two different binders to rx.barTintColor of the same navigation bar and they are feeding the bar conflicting information. You should only have a single binder if at all possible.

Comment: I have only one binders to `rx.barTintColor`, but thanks. I moved setup to viewDidAppear and it's works. And one more question, do you know why it's works with `Observable.of()` and with pre setted title?